# Csv Reader expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, dns, record

I have DNS record as csv format and it has  HostName and IPAdress Label.
İt's include public and private ("192.168", "172.16" and "10.0")IP address and ı want to separate each other. When ı running my code ı took "expected a character buffer object " error code. How can solve this issue

```
import csv
with open('Dns.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
 for row in reader:
  if "10.205" in row['IPAddress']:
  file10=open("Zone10.txt","a")
  a=(row['hostname'], row['IPAddress'])
  file10.write(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are trying to write tuple to `file10`. So next lines should be modified

```
a=(row['hostname'], row['IPAddress'])
file10.write(a)
```

For example, If you're going to write it as a string you can do:

```
file10.write(' '.join(a))  # it will work
```

or

```
a='{}{}'.format(row['hostname'], row['IPAddress'])
file10.write(a)
```

Btw it also would be better to use context manager to open `file10`.

Regarding to comment about CSV output:

```
output = []
for row in reader:
    if "10.205" in row['IPAddress']:
        output.append(row)
if output:
    with open('Zone.csv', 'wb') as zonefile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(zonefile, fieldnames=output[0].keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows([row for row in output])
```

It is very quick-written code, but I hope it will help